# React native on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

**How do I configure react native on android studio?**

I want to synthesize react native on my android studio.How I will do it ?

Comment: `step by step` Stackoverflow is wrong place to ask for guides. Please find one over the internet. If you have some specific problem, like *something is not working for you*, then please be more specific about it

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, install node on your machine. you can download the latest node js (https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and install it.

Please confirm node and npm installation using below commands

node -v

npm -v

Now, you can install react native by using following command in terminal :

npm install -g react-native-cli

We can run react native app in an emulator to test it. For this we have to setup ANDROID_HOME environment variable ( Computer → Advanced System Settings → Environment variables → New, then enter the path to your Android SDK ) .

Create your first project using below command from the folder where you want to create the app.

react-native init demoReactApp

run the command to start package, make sure you started the emulator.

react-native start

The demo project will be open in the emulator.